# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setupZoomOverviewWidth(ZoomManager.java:1195)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob

I have this error in my app and i think that the error is caused by AdMob. I got this stacktrace. I want to know if this error is produced by AdMob or not. Could somebody help me please?

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setupZoomOverviewWidth(ZoomManager.java:1195)
 at android.webkit.ZoomManager.onNewPicture(ZoomManager.java:1136)
 at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setNewPicture(WebViewClassic.java:9021)
 at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebViewClassic.java:8273)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

PHONE_MODEL = K00F
ANDROID_VERSION = 4.2.2

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if this error is produced by AdMob or not

Comment out the code that belongs to the ad (initializing, loading, etc)

- still crashing? - not because of the ad.
- not crashing anymore? - ad caused the crash

Comment: The crash is produced rarely and it seems that it does not fits any pattern.

Comment: I think that the error is caused by AdMob because the only webview is used to display advertising. In any case thanks for your comment

Comment: @TimCastelijns afaik, admob using webview

Comment: same issue here. Almost impossible to reproduce. during testing i received it one time. from the 500k users i have i get arround 20 crash reports per week. 
The only webview is used by admob.